# Scala Cast object to another type

Tags: scala, casting

I want to make following code not throw any error

```
case class A(value: String)
val a = A("I hope to be string one day") 
val value = a.asInstanceOf[String] // java.lang.ClassCastException: A cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

I want to modify class A such that below work

```
val value = a.asInstanceOf[String] // I hope to be string one day
```

does anybody knows the solution?

Comment: define it as an Implicit case class

Comment: `error: illegal combination of modifiers: implicit and case for: class A`

Comment: i can show you what I mean, but all depends on what you are trying to do. Are you trying to provide additional functionality to strings? what is the use-case?

Comment: what would you like to do with that?

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to do `a.asInstanceOf[String]` instead of `a.value` ?

Comment: @maasg @TeWu Thanks for your comment. I actually need this to find a convenient way to use ```spary-json``` https://github.com/spray/spray-json 

It's bit complicated to explain why I need ```a.asInstanceOf[String]``` rather than ```a.value```. 

However, I think I got the answer that looked for thanks to Dylan, though the conclusion is impossible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`A` cannot be cast to a `String` because it **is not a String**. There is nothing you can do to make `a.asInstanceOf[String]` work.

That said, you could **convert** from `A` to `String`, either explicitly or implicitly:

```
// explicit
val s: String = a.value

// implicit conversion (although typically frowned-upon as bad practice)
implicit def unwrapA(a: A): String = a.value
val s: String = a
```

Comment: I think instead of "compile" you mean "not throw a `ClassCastException`".

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned if your use-case is to add additional functionality to an existing class such as `string` you can define an `implict class`

```
implicit class Foo(val s: String) {
    def inc = s.map(c => (c + 1).toChar)
}
```

and then if you can bring this class into scope you can perform the following action

```
"foobarstring".inc //strings now have a function called inc
```

more details on this topic http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html